# scroll for next children, current child fadeOut

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to fadeOut current child div and next child div comes in view when mouse scrolling.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="children">1</div>
<div class="children">2</div>
<div class="children">3</div>
<div class="children">4</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.children {position: sticky; top: 0;}
```

I do this for when scrolled, children 1 stick to top and overlaped by 2.

jquery

```
$('.parent').scroll(function() {
    $(this).children(':first-child').fadeOut();
    $(this).next().children().show();
});
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: *children 1 stick to top and overlapped by 2* - not sure what outcome you're expecting if not this.  When would child-1 fade out?  What should happen when it does?

Comment: What if you set the z-index for each child in reverse (child 1 = z-index:4, child2 = z-index:3 etc) what that give you what you're after?

Comment: Child 1 is in viewport so current child. I expect that When I scroll by mousewheel, child 1 stick to top means remians in viewport but should fadeout and child 2 overlap means comes in viewport. So next child 2 is current and should fadeOut and child 3 overlape. And same for further as scrolling. All child div's are in sequeance and not overlaped as per my layout. But when scrolls they shoud overlaps.